# Excessive HTTP 401s using Windows Authentication, AJAX, ASMX and external ISA

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, asmx, windows-authentication

**Enviornment:**

- ASP.NET WebForms
- .NET 3.5
- jQuery for AJAX
- ASMX web services
- Windows Authentication
- SSL

When we run our production web application, our AJAX calls often have 2-3 HTTP 401s before we get our HTTP 200.  
Is this normal? 
 Is there something we may be doing wrong?

**NOTE:** The calls do not fail, the 401s try until they succeed.

**Example Traffic:**
[image]

Comment: Does this only happen in the beginning (first access) or all the time? Are they always the same calls that fail or is it random?

Comment: Also, what do you see when you look at the network traffic?

Comment: @John - See Fiddler traffic image, is this what you mean?

Comment: mwalker's answer is what I meant. It's a good idea to actually _look_ at the traffic, including the headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's normal traffic for NTLM-style Integrated Windows authentication.  The sequence is roughly:

1. *Client: HTTP GET url...*
2. Server: HTTP 401 WHO GOES THERE
3. *Client: It's-a me, the client!*
4. Server: HTTP 401 YEAH PROVE IT
5. *Client: I've got all the proof you need right here.*
6. Server: HTTP 200 OK

If you look in the raw responses from the server, you should see the Negotiate headers, and the corresponding encoded / encrypted requests from the client.

Comment: Ok cool, I looked at the headers as @John mentioned and I do see the negations taking place.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this? I'm having those same failures and it costs 100-300ms each time.

Comment: use Kerberos instead of NTLM, and the handshake won't need to happen on every request.

Comment: Can you still use integrated/passthrough auth with Kerberos?  I'm seeing the same thing, but only on the production machines (no delays when running on my local PC) but I'd rather not "fix" it by requiring users to log in again.  Also, any idea why the NTLM negotiation has to take place after the first request?  Why can't the client just supply credentials without being asked, for the second and subsequent requests?

Comment: @Malvineous you can disable NTLM to "force" Kerberos - this might be a good option if Kerberos isn't working, as it will force you to fix it.  Kerberos doesn't require the 2 extra requests every time; NTLM does unless you've kept the socket alive (HTTP is stateless, so you could now be someone else)

Comment: @mwalker: But if I was someone else I wouldn't be able to supply the correct user/pass.  What I mean is why am I (the client) sending a request with no credentials, waiting for a 401, then resending with credentials.  Why can't I just send the initial request with my NTLM user/pass to save the server sending me a 401?

Comment: @Malvineous I don't know - probably a good subject for a new question, to see if there's a way to do it.  I presume that it's up to the browser, and IE tries anonymous first on new connections.